# Why is the BGP base on TCP 1027 rather than 179?

Tags: cisco, router, bgp

Why is the BGP foreign address port 1027?

I use BGP to connect Router1 and Router2, but when I show the TCP progress:

```
Router1>show tcp brief 
TCB       Local Address           Foreign Address        (state)
4E976890  10.0.0.1.179           10.0.0.2.1027         ESTABLISHED
```

We say the BGP is based on TCP port 179. Why is Router2's BGP on port 1027?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One side of the connection will have an arbitrary port number, the other will be on 179.

Cisco Press "BGP Fundamentals" has a good explanation ([link](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2756480&seqNum=4))

> the neighbor with the higher IP address manages the connection. The router initiating the request uses a dynamic source port, but the destination port is always 179.
>
> Example 1-1 shows an established BGP session using the command `show tcp brief` to display the active TCP sessions between routers. Notice that the TCP source port is 179 and the destination port is 59884 on R1, and the ports are opposite on R2.

```
Example 1-1: Established BGP session

RP/0/0/CPU0:R1# show tcp brief | exc "LISTEN|CLOSED"
   PCB     VRF-ID     Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address    Foreign Address      State
0x088bcbb8 0x60000000      0      0  10.1.12.1:179    10.1.12.2:59884     ESTAB

R2# show tcp brief
TCB       Local Address               Foreign Address             (state)
EF153B88  10.1.12.2. 59884            10.1.12.1.179               ESTAB
```

This is just the same as any other TCP connection: the passive open side sits and waits on a well-known port number; the active open side uses an arbitary port.  This makes it much easier to manage many-to-many TCP links.

Comment: What's the correct way to protect these random ports in iptables?

Comment: Question is about Cisco routers, what are you wanting to protect with `iptables`?

Comment: @bswinnerton - most likely you will only filter on connection-initiating traffic (`--dport 179`) and let the connection tracking mechanism handle the responses (`--state ESTABLISHED`, for example?)

Answer (score 5):

TCP source vs. destination ports.

To give a different example: HTTP servers listen on TCP port 80. So when you are connecting to a web server, you will automatically use TCP/80 as the destination port. However, the source port is a random one above 1024.

The exact same thing happens with BGP - the client (the router initiating the connection) will connect to TCP destination port 179. But the source port for that connection will be a random high port.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the `BGP` use TCP `179` port as the BGP service. the client connect BGP service port there is no limit.

such as the SSH server use `22` as its port, there is no limit for the client port.